# C# timestamp to js

Tags: javascript, c#, time

I am trying to recreate a C# timestamp in javascript but am not successfull :-/

Here is how my C# timestamp looks like:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
now = new DateTime (now.Year, 1, 1);
int yearDay = (int)(now.Subtract (new DateTime (1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```

This is the return: **1483228800**

I have tried this in javascript:

```
var now = new Date();
now = new Date(now.Year, 1, 1);
var yearDay = ((now.(new Date(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds);
```

But that gives me an error :-/

Hoping for help with this and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You can't copy and paste code between different languages. Don't even attempt it, it is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the timestamp you can do:

```
var d = new Date(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var timestamp = Math.floor(d / 1000); //this would be your timestamp
```

```js
var d = new Date(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var timestamp = Math.floor(d / 1000);
console.log(timestamp);
```

Comment: This seems almost correct, but does not give the timestamp as the c#? This is what I get: 1485907200. I have changed the 2016 to 2017. Any ideas?

Comment: There is some GMT issues right there. Note that if you convert the value back, then it is OK... http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Comment: Well, when converting back I get this date: Wed Feb 01 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET). How do I solve this?

Comment: I´m getting 1454295600. Try it on codepen. That´s the reaseon why I told you the GMT issue

Comment: I added snippet

Comment: I got the right timestamp like this: new Date(2017, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) changed to Date.UTC(2017, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0). Thanks for guiding me in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000)
```

It should return a timestamp in seconds. Also you can use the more accurate method:

```
new Date().valueOf()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply your timestamp by 1000 to convert to `ms` and pass result directly to `new Date()`

You will need to print the timestamp, you can't mix language variables directly since your C# runs on server and javascript in the browser

```js
var d= new Date(1483228800 * 1000)
console.log(d)
```